# How to find stack of Project Browser ? - livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to delete stack with my button.

Here code:

```
delete stack stackname
```

Before delete command I want to find stack name of Project Browser.If true is pass command.

How do I do ?

Comment: I'm not sure what data you need - can you clarify?  The project browser stack is 'revProjectBrowser' (I assume you don't want to delete that!) and you can get a list of open stacks with 'the openStacks' (check the dictionary entry for 'openStacks').

Comment: @splash21 I want to get name stack list.Can you show example code for me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use either the revloadedStacks() function, or the openstacks() function. Possibly you're also interested in the mainstacks() function. I suggest you check them all out in the dictionary.

```
on mouseUp
   put revloadedstacks() into field 1
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! If I want to stack name when I hilite of project browser.How do I do ?